# Verificar posição do click em um ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma tela que possui um `ListView` dentro dela, preciso identificar em qual linha foi clicada para direcionar para o local correto. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`setOnItemClickListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) desta forma:

```
listItemView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, listItemsValue[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Neste meu caso resulta numa mensagem `Toast` na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Detalhes

- [Set onclicklistener in listview in android programmatically](http://www.android-examples.com/set-onclicklistener-in-listview-in-android-programmatically/)
- [AdapterView - setOnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Boa sorte.

Comment: Posso fazer uns IF dentro do setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: @carlosgiovanicasilo sim, sempre.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.